# Sending message via Facebook throws 500 error

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am sending a private message via facebook from my app (website). It is an invitation link to the website - however, it gives the following error:

```
The website encountered an error while retrieving https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition
```

The link invitation link being sent is something like 
http://myapp.com/invitation - doesnt work
http://myapp.com - works!

How can I make it work with something after a forward slash?

The actual code:

```
  :javascript
    $(function(){
      $('li.friend:not(.invited) label').live('click', function() {
        FB.init({appId: #{Rails.application.config.fb_app_id}, xfbml: true, cookie: true})
        FB.ui({
          method: 'send',
          display: 'popup',
          name: 'New Invitation',
          link: 'http://myapp.com/invitation/',
          to: this.parentNode.getAttribute("data-id"),
          frictionlessRequests:true,
          show_error: 'true'
        })
        $(this).parent().addClass("invited")
        $(this).siblings().prop("checked", true)
      })
    });
```

Comment: You have 'frictionlessRequests' and 'method: send' there; those aren't compatible options, the frictionlessrequests option is for the requests dialog - not necessarily the cause of this problem, but make sure you're following the documentation for the send dialog correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 'frictionlessRequests' and 'method: send' there; those aren't compatible options. The `frictionlessRequests: true`, should be in your FB.init() call and affects how the Requests dialog works when pre-filling recipients, what you have there is a mix of parameters from different dialogs

A sample [send dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) call is:

```
  FB.ui({
          method: 'send',
          name: 'People Argue Just to Win',
          link: 'http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html',
          });
```

and a sample [apprequests dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/):

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'Come use this app with me.'
  });
}
```

Also (as you discovered) the link needs to resolve correctly a return a 200 response; if it redirects immediately it won't work correctly

Comment: I removed the frictionlessRequestion line, but we still get the same problem. I thought it might be because the redirect_uri isn't specified, so I added a redirect back to the same page (I'm pretty sure it worked in the past without the redirect). Now, we get an error stating the page is not owned by our app (even localhost apparently isn't owned)

Comment: The redirect_uri needs to be derived from your app's domain - is that the case? For the redirect_uri, if the app is in a page tab and doesn't have a canvas or website implementation i think you need to redirect to the place on your site that the content is rendered from (e.g. mysite.com/pagetabapp1/ ) - this wouldn't be the case if you're sending requests though as requests can't be sent for apps that don't have a canvas implementation

Comment: That is the problem - The link redirects to a certain page in my app. Facebook does not like 302 responses - looks like only accepts 200. If you mention this in your answer - I will mark it as accepted ;)

Comment: I can confirm that this happens on our site when the link 302's. However, subsequent attempts to share the same link are fruitless, as I think FB caches that URL and 500's without doing another request. Anyone know how to cache bust this on FB?

Comment: @haider - use [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to clear the cache

Comment: thanks @igy, I didn't see anything specific about clearing the cache? Does it just clear it when i run debug?

Comment: it clears on scrape, which happens approx every 24 hours, or when you use the debug tool